# Sessions issue in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

From time to time, lets say 2 or 3 months, I get the following error in laravel in a browser session that is open for all those 2 or 3 months:

> ErrorException
>
> unserialize(): Error at offset 106 of 480 bytes
>
> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Store.php

```
protected function readFromHandler()
{
    $data = $this->handler->read($this->getId());

    return $data ? unserialize($data) : array();
}
```

Opening a hidden session in Chrome or just closing and opening the browser solves the problem.

Any idea what can it be?

Comment: You mean to say that you've kept a browser open for three months and you have the same session which now throws an exception?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `$data` is not a properly serialize `variable`. you can `dd` the variable and check if it is properly `serialize` or a raw data.